# How to determine the type of a numerical value passed as a string without losing data or being converted to wrong datatype

Tags: php

I want to allow users to submit numerical values through an online form but I've ran into a problem trying to validate the correct datatype(integer or float) for the submitted value.

Lets say a user submits:

```
3.14
```

I cannot use **is_float()** because the user-value is technically a string.

**floatval()** would work, except when the user only supplies an integer **floatval()** still considers it a float instead of an integer.

```
gettype(floatval("3"))
```

returns **float**, but I need it to return **integer**.

I even tried checking if it was an integer like this:

```
is_int(floatval(3)) // returns false
```

But why does the above return **false**?
The below prints **3** as if it was an integer:

```
echo floatval(3)
```

Therefore, I need a function that can be able to tell the difference between a float and integer passed as a string so it doesn't

1. pass an integer off as a float.
2. doesn't truncate a float into an integer.

Pattern checking with regular expressions could possibly be a solution, but are there any other alternatives?

**NOTE:** I am not using classes or objects and I prefer not to if possible.

Comment: What if the user submits `3.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a float and integer, then check if they're equal.

```
$i = intval($input);
$f = floatval($input);
if ($i == $f) {
    $type = "int";
} else {
    $type = "float";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below function will solve your problem

```
function checkType($inputNumber){
    if (strpos($inputNumber, '.') !== false) {
        return 'Number is float';
    } else {
        return 'Number is integer';
    }
}

echo checkType(3.5);  o/p Number is float.
echo checkType(3);  o/p Number is integer.
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, If you checking float then obviously it will only return true or false on float value weather or not it's a integer.

You are checking for float then how can you expect that it will return integer. Use intval() to check integer value.

```
<?php
    echo intval(42);                      // 42
    echo intval(4.2);                     // 4
    echo intval('42');                    // 42
    echo intval('+42');                   // 42
    echo intval('-42');                   // -42
    echo intval(042);                     // 34
    echo intval('042');                   // 42
    echo intval(1e10);                    // 1410065408
    echo intval('1e10');                  // 1
```

Or you can do one thing you can check if dot(.) exist then check with floatval() and not then check with intval()

> **You can alos do something like following**

```
<?php

  $a = '1.6';

  if(str_pos($a, '.') !== 'false){
     $a = intval($a);
  }else{
     $a = floatval($a);
  }
```